# How to combine 2 columns from 2 database sources in Informatica Powercenter (9.1)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am using Informatica PowerCenter 9.1 and am trying to combine 2 columns from 2 sources. Basically trying to create a report that will show all users and the roles they have on 2 separate databases. They could be in one database and not the other so I have to account for that as well.

So if I had this output:
**DATABASE 1 (Oracle)**

User 1 = Role A

User 2 = Role B

**DATABASE 2 (Sybase)**

User 1 = Role C

User 3 = Role D

I want the output to look like this:

User 1 = Role A --- Role C

User 2 = Role B --- N/A

User 3 = N/A --- Role D

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry all, after I posted this I figured out a solution to this. What I did was similar to Koushik's response below.

Answer (score 0):

You can us joiner transformation to link them together and then use expression to concat.

1. Read from database using 2 separate source qualifier transformation and join them using joiner. 
   Join condition would be user_id. Join type should be full outer join. Full join will pick up all data (matching and not-matching) in either table.
2. Then pickup user_id, role1(Oracle) and role 2 (Sybase) and concat them with IFNULL logic like this -
   IIF (ISNULL(role1), 'N/A', role1)||IIF (ISNULL(role2), 'N/A', role2)

Answer (score -1):

To concatenate two columns from two different tables into a single column at target will not work in Informatica. You can combine only columns in a single table. But there is a work around and it is using "Post SQL" query and here you can write a database JOIN query.